# При значении инпута появляется блок

Tags: jquery

При получении значения из **inpit**,  нужно чтоб появлялся еще один блок, 
если это значение равно 2 то появляется второй блок, если 3-ом то третий блок.Не могу понять, что не так.
[Пример](https://codepen.io/kiryha_cq/pen/eygegK?editors=1111)

```js
$("#someInput").blur(function() {
  var someI = $('#someInput').val();

  console.log($('#someInput').val());
  if (someI > 0) {
    $('#someInput0').removeClass('delete');
  }
  if (someI > 1) {
    $('#someInput1').removeClass('delete');
  }
  if (someI > 2) {
    $('#someInput2').removeClass('delete');
  }
});
```

```css
.delete {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-input">
  <div class="static-block">
    <label class="control-label" for="n">Кол-во этажей:       </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="n" name="n" value="3" id="someInput">
  </div>
  <div class="inpu-1">
    <label class="control-label" for="a">Периметр 1 этажа:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control left_input" name="a" id="a" placeholder="" value="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control left_input" name="b" id="b" placeholder="" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="inpu-2 delete" id="someInput1">
    <label id="" class="control-label">Периметр 2 этажа:</label>
    <input type="text" id="a2" class="form-control left_input" name="a2" value="">
    <input type="text" id="b2" class="form-control left_input" name="b2" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="inpu-3 delete" id="someInput2">
    <label id="" class="control-label">Периметр 3 этажа:</label>
    <input type="text" id="a3" class="form-control left_input" name="a3" value="">
    <input type="text" id="b3" class="form-control left_input" name="b3" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `id="n"` - убрать!

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!!!